# What limitations will I run into making a game with Allegro / SDL vs. OpenGL / DirectX?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, sdl, allegro

So I have a bunch of experience with C++ and Win32 programming and I am looking to create a 2D game with a couple of friends of mine. I have also dipped my toe into DirectX and OpenGL, but would prefer to use as simple of a library / API as possible when developing this game both for reducing the learning curve and making the development process easier / faster. However, I don't want to limit myself to much with regards to what I can and can't do in my game based on my choice here. What functionality / features would I lose out on by going with something like Allegro or SDL vs jumping straight into OpenGL lets say. I realize you can do other things aside from just graphics with Allegro, etc., but will I be able to build a fully featured game with something like Allegro?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to create a good game with libraries like Allegro. There is a few nice games in their [depot](https://www.allegro.cc/depot/index/pop) to prove that. And I remember a few shareware games created using Allegro. It all depends on what kind of game you want to create.

But AFAIK Allegro and SDL are C libraries and if you are familiar with C++, you may try SFML or Cinder which could further simplify the process.

If you are only into creating a game comfortably and don't care about the technology used maybe using a complete engine like Unity3D or Unreal engine, which are free until you make a considerable profit out of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You will miss out the lighting part you generally do in a fragment shader. Other than that, using a pure 2D api can significantly reduce your amount of code, because you do not need to write your own shaders, nor the interface between shader and c++ code which is often even more work and maintenance than the shader itself. Since shader code is mandatory in modern OpenGl my recommendation is SDL2.